# How can I remove this tile window stool without compromising the installation of the vinyl window?

Tags: windows, tile

I'm planning to replace the tile window stool below this window with a piece of quartz countertop. In this picture, I have already removed part of the thick tan tile the stool is made of.

[image]

It looks like the window might be sitting on top of the tile, in which case removing 100% of the tile will remove support from underneath the window. Is the window actually supported by the tile? How can I prepare the area for a new window stool without compromising the installation of the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All windows I've seen were supported at least in part on the sides by nail fins or directly through the frame. Even if your window is technically bottom supported (I can't imagine there is such a vinyl window) there should be enough support from surrounding finish materials to remove the tile and fill in the gap with another material without the window moving in the short term. It may eventually settle if it were intended to be bottom supported and left without support, but it would take a while for the surrounding materials to give up their grip.

You will not have a problem removing material under the window.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just cut the leading edge of the tile off and leave the body of the tile in place. Then put your new stool over the exisitng stool? The cut face of the old stool can be covered with the wall surfacing material.